# Block bot sites through .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bots, spam

I just wrote some rewrite conditions in order to block a bunch of bot sites. I successfully blocked many of them except three containing a hyphen (dash). So, since they all contain also the word "buttons" I tried to intercept them all with the following Rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*buttons.*\.com/ [NC,OR]
```

The whole rewrite code in my <kbd>.htaccess</kbd> looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*buttons.*\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*darodar\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*webextract\.net/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*makemoneyonline\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*semalt\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*ranksonic\.info/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*smailik\.com/ [NC]
```

The 3 websites I am failing in blocking are:

```
social-buttons.com
buttons-for-website.com
simple-share-buttons.com
```

And some variations of those, with subdomain.

My take is that the condition above should intercept them. But I keep getting spammed. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is the best answer I have found as to why it won't work to change settings in apache's files.  It never even hits apache!  It just pings GA directly.  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914

Comment: Another best answer!  http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/

Comment: hi all, thanks for the answers: @Mark thanks for the suggestions, i've tried to escape the dashes with no luck, maybe because i kept the trailing slash and the http:// i am gonna try again that solution without trailing slash and without http:// thanks also @bloodyKnukles!

Comment: Question though: can I leave the initial ^? I've read in the apache documentation that the webserver needs that symbol to know when the string to match starts. Thanks again

Comment: The ^ is the anchor for the start of regex.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html.  You don't have to keep it but it will keep the regex a little tighter.

Comment: I deleted a prior message because it contained inaccurate information. My subsequent answers were for social-buttons.com.  Restated:
I use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*buttons\-for\-website\.com [NC,OR]`.  I haven't solved social-buttons.com yet. Would this be better in serverfault.com?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for you advices. Checking the results today it seems like I have solved 2 of the last 3 spam bot sites with those rules. The one i can't solve is the same one that you can't solve: social-buttons.com - if its true that it pings GA directly without passing from the webserver, do you have any idea what can be done?

Comment: Maybe just filter it out from the GA dashboard?

Comment: .htaccess will only work for semalt, the rest of referrers dont reach your site so is pointless to add them. the only way for now is filter them, here you can find more information about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362