# I've had Google Analytics disabled on my site for more than a month, but data keeps coming in

Tags: node.js, google-analytics

This entire data set should have 0 visits.  I have a one page site (nodejs) and have removed the analytics from the site more than a month ago.  Just tonight I took a look at the GA data on their site and here's what I witnessed.  Why are there still tons of views on my site on GA?

For curiosity's sake, I added GA on my site two nights ago and site visits have actually increased over the past few days, but not to the extend New Relic is tracking site visits.  Any thoughts?  This just seems creepy or maybe manipulative on Google's part.

[image: GA_Weirdness]

Comment: Are the sessions really originating from your own website? Look at the Hostnames report, and see if it really is traffic from your own domain. Probably someone has hi-jacked your Analytics tracking code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely **ghost spam**.  Check your referrals, you will probably have hits from `free-social-buttons or guardlink`, they don't need that the code is active is enough if it's created.

Here is an example of one of my inactive accounts.

[image]

You can find more information about ghost spam on this related questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81491/49561
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312117/3197362
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717606/3197362

If it isn't spam then probably someone is using your tracking code somehow as @MrSponge mention.