# Google Analytics Real-time overview shows a page that doesn't exist

Tags: google-analytics

I don't understand this. How can this happen?
I have an educational site and when I looked at Google Analytics I saw a porn page in active page which doesn't exist on my site.
What is this and how can I stop this from happening?
I checked for that page on my website and there is no such page.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [why are porn stuff sites appearing on my google analytics data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717151/why-are-porn-stuff-sites-appearing-on-my-google-analytics-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 In Google Analytics, go to the **Admin tab**.
>
> 2 Go to **View Column** and select **Filters**.
>
> 3 Click on **New Filter**.
>
> 4 Put **Spam Porn Referrals** as a name for the Filter.
>
> 5  *Filter Type* select **Custom**.  *Filter Field*, find and select **Campaign
>   Source**. In the *Filter Pattern* text box, copy and paste this Regular
>   Expression.

```
depositfiles-porn.ga|youporn-forum.ga|pornhub-forum.ga|generalporn.org|rapidgator-porn.ga|meendo-free-traffic.ga|amanda-porn.ga|torture.ml|pornhub-forum.uni.me
```

> 6 Click Save.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a hit for a Page on your website, it is rather a Referral (i.e. the source from which a user was supposedly coming from before landing on your site): https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en

It is actually spam generated by bots and crawlers, and you can follow the steps listed in this article to mitigate this issue: http://moz.com/blog/how-to-stop-spam-bots-from-ruining-your-analytics-referral-data

For the most common sources of Referral Spam, you might want to add an *Exclude Filter* to simply [ignore those hits](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034842?hl=en):

> To filter out a referring source from your reports, create the following filter:
>
> - *Filter Type*: Custom Filter > Exclude
> - *Filter Field*: Campaign Source
> - *Filter Pattern*: Enter the domain of the referring source that you would like to exclude, for example, google.com. You can use regular expressions if you would like to exclude several referring sources.

If you are wondering about the "Active Page" view listing a spammy-looking URL, it is because that page most likely is a 404 page your website serves in response to the request.

Note that the URL also begins with a slash delimiter ("/"), as in `yourwebsite.com/www.spammy-site.com` -- this will show up in Analytics as `/www.spammy-site.com`, as in the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

This is **Ghost Referrer Spam**, and it shows as both **pages and/or referrals**(you can see it in the screenshot bellow). This "visits" never reach your website actually. The only thing you should worry about is your data since it **affects your statistics by adding useless data** to your Google Analytics.

The only way to stop them for now is by filtering them in Google Analytics as @Philippe mention you can add a **single filter** or you can use a more general approach with a filter based on **Valid Hostnames** that will stop this and most of the Referrer Spam.

Basically, this works by excluding all hits that don't have any of your valid hostnames since the **spammers don't know who are they targeting** they use a fake or empty hostname as you can see in the screenshots

Here is more information about this solution and others https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link also. I have seen the same problem and now i am done with this.
[Stop Spam or adult site referrals in google analytics](http://www.vivekmoyal.in/stop-spam-from-adult-site-referrals-in-google-analytics/)