# Google Analytics User Flow

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am looking at my Google Analytics user flow. Normally this just shows which pages people have visited on my site

In the 'Other Pages' section I can see that some visitors are visiting a website page that is not mine - its clearly some form of dodgy website. - ie they seem to be getting to that website through some link on my website?

How can I stop this or solve the problem? Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to NSFW-looking Referral Sites appearing in your Analytics reports? If so, you might want to check out @carlos 's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717151/why-are-porn-stuff-sites-appearing-on-my-google-analytics-data

Comment: Referral spambots will cause many of your metrics to be inaccurate, so it's best to filter them out ASAP! There are lots more than just the one you mentioned. [Here's a quick list to get you started](https://gist.github.com/chrisblakley/e31a07380131e726d4b5), but be sure to stay up on them- especially if your site is not a high-traffic website. I'm hoping that these adult-oriented ones are the catalyst to get Google to actually step in do something about these bots.