# Very Weird pageviews in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, pageviews

I have access to over 100 GA profiles and I've never seen this before.

In a newly created analytics account (3 days ago) we're seeing some pageviews that have the following format:

/www.torture.ml/reply734532

/www.pornhub-forum.ga/topic42854

The website is for a plumbing company.

Notice how the url structure begins with "/" and then has another url (not related to our site at all) after it.

Any thoughts on how these urls could be making it into our analytics account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why are porn stuff sites appearing on my google analytics data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717151/why-are-porn-stuff-sites-appearing-on-my-google-analytics-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as *Ghost Referrer Spam*.

For more information, you might want to read @carlos 's excellent answer to a similar question: [Why are porn sites appearing in my Google Analytics data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717151/why-are-porn-stuff-sites-appearing-on-my-google-analytics-data/29717606#29717606)

Here's an extract answering your concerns:

> This is Ghost Referrer Spam, there's no flaw in your app/site regarding this aspect. They just target random GA tracking-ID's no matter if it's an app or a website, it's called Ghost because it doesn't reach/use your app actually.
>
> You shouldn't worry about security issues but if you want to keep clean your google analytics is better to exclude them from your reports
>
> The only way to stop them for now is by filtering them in Google Analytics you can add a single filter:
>
> > - Go to Admin tab in Google Analytics
> > - Select the View you want to filter > Filter > New Filter
> > - In Filter Type choose Custom Filter > Exclude Filter
> > - Field: Campaign Source
> > - Filter Pattern: Enter youporn-forum.ga or any referral spam that is hitting you