# Referral spam mobile app

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

Do you know some way to stop referral spam appear in google analytics in an ios app? What I am already doing is adding an exclude filter by domain, but I need to constantly update those filters as new domains appear very often, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **valid hostname filter** this will prevent most of the referrer spam from showing in your GA, and it requires a lot less maintenance. You can see more details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717606/3197362

And just as a tip **to exclude referrals you shouldn't use domain**, google recommends using Campaign Source

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034842?hl=en

Comment: Ok, that's good if we are talking about web, but this is an ios app, so I can't exclude that traffic in that way, any suggestions?