# Google Analytics - What is "Vitaly rules google ☆*:.｡...)ﾉʕ•̫͡•ʔᶘ ᵒᴥᵒᶅ(=^. .^=)oO"?

Tags: google-analytics, spam

I was checking my Google Analytics Realtime Overview and I found the following.
Is it harmful to my site? Should I take any precautions?

[image]

Comment: This question belongs on another stack exchange network webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [why are porn stuff sites appearing on my google analytics data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717151/why-are-porn-stuff-sites-appearing-on-my-google-analytics-data)

Comment: even i started getting all these on my site now. from 'Vitaly rules google' to 'blackhatworld.com' to 'reditt.com'. Strange. and why now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as described in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It's probably on-topic on Webmasters SE.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**UPDATE December 13th 2016**: The person behind this is back again, this time sending spam as a **language** with a similar message:

> Vitaly rules google ☆*:｡゜ﾟ･*ヽ(^ᴗ^)ﾉ*･゜ﾟ｡:*☆
>   ¯_(ツ)_/¯(ಠ益ಠ)(ಥ‿ಥ)(ʘ‿ʘ)ლ(ಠ_ಠლ)( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)ヽ(ﾟДﾟ)ﾉʕ•̫͡•ʔᶘ ᵒᴥᵒᶅ(=^ ^=)oO

The method in the original answer was only for keyword spam. For a more comprehensive solution, the following guide will help prevent this and any other type of spam in Google Analytics.

[Ultimate Guide to Getting Rid of the Spam and Other Junk Traffic in Google Analytics](https://www.ohow.co/ultimate-guide-to-removing-irrelevant-traffic-in-google-analytics/)

---

This is Spam. Vitaly is the name behind some of the last Referrer Spam hitting Google Analytics. But this time is using a different method with keywords.

This type of spam **never accesses your site** so you don't have to worry about security on your site. The only thing you should do is **stop it with filters** in GA to **keep clean your stats**.

- Go to **Admin tab** in Google Analytics
- Select the **View** you want to filter > **Filter** > **New Filter**
- In *Filter Type* choose **Custom Filter** > Exclude Filter
- *Field*: **Campaign Term**
- *Filter Pattern*: Enter **Vitaly rules google**

And here you can find information about this specific issue

https://www.ohow.co/secret-%C9%A2oogle-com-trump-spam-google-analytics/

Related answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

Comment: It seems like a bunch of different spam text is coming through from the same service provider. I ended up just excluding the service provider. The filter is called "ISP Organization".

Comment: Unfortunately, that will only apply to this particular spammer, but others will still get through. The hostname filter is the best option about this type of spam

Answer (score 1):

If you need to how how to get rid of this garbage, it is as simple as creating a filter in Google Analytics. Many people have mentioned editing the htaccess file, but I haven't found a way to do it like that yet.

Just create a custom exclusion filter. If you need the exact specifics, check out this post on [how to remove vitaly rules google](http://www.getfluid.com/vitaly-rules-google/)