# Spam Referral people on my Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, spam

for some time in google Analytics I observe very busy with foreign sites. These are spam site. How can I protect?
Screen GA:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2vctdae.jpg

Comment: First of all your linked picture is unavailable but also it's best to fully describe your problem here rather than use a picture that will most likely not be available in the future for people having the same question as you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why are porn stuff sites appearing on my google analytics data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717151/why-are-porn-stuff-sites-appearing-on-my-google-analytics-data)

Answer (score 1):

These are called "Ghost Referrals" and the best way to rid yourself of them is to add a new view and create an Include filter for it.

**Check out the full post** http://blog.tylerbuchea.com/google-analytics-filtering-out-ghost-referrals/

First go the the Analytics Admin section and choose the Account and Property you'd like to apply the filter to. Then create a new view like "example.com (Ghost Referalls Filter)". Trust me on this create a new one and don't reuse your existing one. I'll explain later.

Add a new filter to your freshly created view. Then select the Custom tab, mark the Include radio button, and choose Hostname from the dropdown. Then you'll want to enter your sites hostnames separated with the OR operator "|" and make sure to add a backslash before each period. This will white list only your hostnames and block any other sites from sending fake data that muddy up your Analytics reports.

**Example entry**

`example\.com|www\.example\.com|translate\.google\.com`

[image: Google Analytics Add Filter Screenshot]

**So Why The New View?**

If you add a filter to an existing view it will permanently change that view and all of the past data.

**I Don't See Any Data**

Unfortunately Analytics doesn't apply filters to past data. So all of the data in the filtered view will be from the day it was assigned onwards. Just give it a few days and you'll be using your original view less and less.

Answer (score 0):

If your picture is what I think it is, its actually a GA issue. Its fake referral spam.

https://megalytic.com/blog/how-to-filter-out-fake-referrals-and-other-google-analytics-spam