# How is Google Analytics providing data for my site without the JS code?

Tags: google-analytics, bots, spam

I signed up for Google Analytics a couple months ago, but have yet to actually set up the JS snippet on my site.

Today I logged into the dashboard and I see tons of tracking data already in there.

I'm trying to figure out how Google is gathering user data on my site when I haven't even hooked up the code yet.

Also, I see a handful of hits to completely random paths on my domain (mostly foreign). Stuff like `www.mysite.com/www.somepornsite.com` and I'm just curious why a bot would even bother trying to hit a full domain as a subpath. Or even why my site's getting hit at all (it's completely behind HTTPAuth at the moment), but I suppose that's inevitable.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why are porn stuff sites appearing on my google analytics data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717151/why-are-porn-stuff-sites-appearing-on-my-google-analytics-data)

Comment: This is ghost spam, it doesn't need that the code is active its enough if it's created to hit you, just follow the link @nyuen put, it talks about this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of months ago, it turned oud that a bot got my script and did malicious things with it. I got my self a new Analytics code and it did the trick for me.

This will probably also work for you although it it weird that they got your script without even having it published yet.