# Removing spam referrals in Google Analytics doesn't work anymore for some referrers

Tags: google-analytics, referrer-spam

I set up some filters in Google Analytics to remove spam referrals. It works great for the majority of the referral links but since last week, three websites are showing up again. What's the reason for this and how to make them disappear again?

**Filter 1**

```
darodar\.com|priceg\.com|semalt\.com|buttons\-for\-website\.com|makemoneyonline\.com|blackhatworth\.com|hulfingtonpost\.com|bestwebsitesawards\.com|simple\-share\-buttons\.com
```

Filter 2

```
econom\.co|ilovevitaly\.com|ilovevitaly\.ru|humanorightswatch\.org|free\-share\-buttons\.com|buy\-cheap\-online\.info|domination\.ml|mobiletest\.me|site2\.free\-share\-buttons\.com
```

**Filter 3**

```
Get\-Free\-Traffic\-Now\.com|googlsucks\.com|theguardlan\.com|quirktools\.com|guardlink\.org|site3\.free\-share\-buttons\.com|site4\.free\-share\-buttons\.com
```

**Filter 4**

```
Site5\.free\-share\-buttons\.com|site6\.free\-share\-buttons\.com|event\-tracking\.com|free\-social\-buttons\.com
```

The following three referrers show up again in Google Analytics.

- www.Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com (Filter 3)
- free-social-buttons.com (Filter 4)
- www.event-tracking.com (Filter 4)

**EDIT:**

Someone marked this as a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666318/how-to-block-spam-referrers-like-darodar-com-from-accessing-website) but that's not correct. The answer there suggests using filters but that's exactly what I've been doing for the last couple of months. Someone else suggested looking for fake hostnames but I only see the valid one so nothing to block there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Block Spam Referrers like darodar.com from Accessing Website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666318/how-to-block-spam-referrers-like-darodar-com-from-accessing-website)

Comment: Noticed the same thing recently. The suggested answer in the comment above actually suggests the very thing we're already doing (filtering through GA) but doesn't address what to do when they get past the filter somehow. I'm seeing free-social-buttons.com come through despite have 3 individual Filters set up for it.

Comment: FYI, I posted in the GA forum about this as well. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/ffF6uXUPQSs;context-place=forum/analytics

Comment: What are you using as a filter field?

Comment: Use **Campaign Source** instead and your filters will work http://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

Answer (score 0):

The method I found the best was to use custom dimension as the filter.

The "spam" is not spam on your page, it's only your GA-code that is used on a different page.
Since the "spam" is never on your page they can't know what dimension or how to use it.
So..

In your Javascript code add a dimension like:

```
<script>
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', XXXXXXX, 'auto');
   ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'dimension1':  'true'
   });

</script>
```

This sends a custom dimension with the value "true".
In Analytics you add it to the Custom Definitions -> Custom Dimensions.

Then in filtering you INCLUDE on this custom dimension if it contains "true" value.
So only data with a Custom Dimension1 with value "true" is counted. If the spammers finds this out.
Then they are good :-)

This way you will only get true data on Google Analytics and no strange referals.
I have had this running for about a year on my page now and have no strange referals anymore.
All referals I have in GA is true referals.