# Google Analytics: Get ride of spam sessions with filter

Tags: google-analytics

I see this referral in my sessions. However i've applied a filter to exclude it.

```
www.Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com / referral
```

The filter is even at the top, so i don't know why it is not working:

*And this is different than the suggested similar question, in the sense that this question uses a filter inside Google Analytics. The other question talks about modifying the hosting.*

Here you can see my set up for the filter:

[image]

This is what i see:

[image]

Comment: I can't help you with your specific problem, but that looks like an awfully broad pattern that may exclude legitimate visits, as well.

Comment: I've tried to be more specific but nevertheless it still appeared. 
Any hint is welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Block Spam Referrers like darodar.com from Accessing Website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666318/how-to-block-spam-referrers-like-darodar-com-from-accessing-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't use `.*Get.*` as a filter pattern, any referral with get in the name will be filtered.

Second you should use **Campaign Source** instead as filter field of Referral

For the *file pattern* add something like this

```
Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com|event-tracking.com|free-share-buttons.com
```

You can keep adding spammers up until 255 characters. If you want to prevent ghost spam instead of adding it to a filter every time you can use a **Valid hostname filter**, you can find more information here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

Comment: You don't need to put www at the beginning? Thanks i'll try this.

Comment: No, it's not needed, in fact, you don't even need to put the `.com` at the end since these names are too specific already.

Comment: So it is like using: ".*name-of-referral.*" .* captures anything at the beggining and at the end. right?

Comment: yes that's right, but you don't need to add `.*`, GA simplifies the REGEX. so basically what you put between the bars `|`  will match anything containing it. So be careful because if the name of the referral is common for example `www.button.info` then is better the whole referrer.