# Google Analytics fake visits, but very different

Tags: google-analytics

Like many others I suffered the fake referrals and spam stuff in my google analytics, I have put all the relevant filters in place and read the forums and tips, etc.

Everything seemed to settle down, but now I can see big spikes in real-time visits, like 25/35 all at once, just showing landing on my homepage, there is no 'fake' address showing up like before (free-share-buttons, you-porn.ga etc), nothing, just multiple visits all at once, the locations are spread across the world, but mostly in the USA, this seems to be happening once a day from what I can tell. What is causing this?

I'm actually at the point where I'm thinking, GA not even worth bothering with for a small business like mine, frustrating and just seem to be wasting precious time on stuff like this.

Comment: Could you let us know what the "relevant filters" you put in place are?

Answer (score 0):

Fake direct visits are the latest form of attack from ghost spam, especially from `free-share-buttons`. If you catch it in real time you will see that this spammer(might be others) makes **1 referral hit with multiple fake direct visits** (10 or more)  at the same time.

The problem with the **conventional methods** is that they were excluding the source, in this case, the referrals, and while the referral will still be stopped, **the fake direct visit will go through**.

Fortunately, there is a way to prevent the direct visits along with the referral and any ghost spam form for that matter, like organic or pages.

What all **ghost spam have in common** is that they use a **fake or not set hostname**. Based on this if you create a **filter that will include only valid hostnames** you will get rid of all fake direct visits and ghost referrals with one filter.

You can find **more information** on these related questions about this issue and the valid hostname solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30470413/3197362

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

Comment: Carlos thanks for your reply, I have now done an 'include' hostname filter, hopefully this will work. I'm just hoping that google actually sort this out, the more you look on forums its just a huge problem, if it continues I will just delete my GA account because the time I have spent on blocking fake results is just not worth it to my business, my time is better spent doing more productive things, any way, lets see, wait and hope :-))