# strange screen names in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

In Google Analytics I see some strange screen names:

```
sbwc.rf.lk.jc.gzh.trd
lyi.lcvx.oalsl.a
dfz.eoug.vafjc.a
iic.fv.xtd
```

Those names are not present in the original Android app and are also not in the Proguard mappings file. Also, statistics show app versions I never published.
Does this mean that somebody pirated the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be caused by Ghost Spam. This type of spam can fake almost any dimension. Check your referrals and look for anything suspicious.

Here is an example:

[image]

You can check this related question for more info about the Spam and a way to solve it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362