# Google Analytics: Referral traffic with hostname not set

Tags: google-analytics

Preparing to filter spam content I've analyzed the data and found some direct and referral traffic where the hostname is (not set). I assume the direct traffic is spam as it has a bounce rate of 100% and an average session duration of 0:00.

But I'm not sure what the referral traffic is. This traffic has a bounce rate of 76.43% and an average session duration of 00:00:48. What can this traffic be? Spam? An error in the google analytics tracker implementation on the website? Web Crawler? ...

Answer (score 0):

The not set hostname is a clear sign of ghost spam, it doesn't matter if the time and bounce rate look normal. Spammers can easily manipulate this.(See image below)

You can find more information on these related questions.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81491

**Spam / Hostname**
[image]