# htaccess to block any request with referer set

Tags: .htaccess, referrer

This question is not the same as [How to Block Spam Referrers like darodar.com from Accessing Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666318/how-to-block-spam-referrers-like-darodar-com-from-accessing-website#) as that question hightlight on how to block a specific referer.

This question is about to block any request with Referer set and give them a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

The example above returns a 404 not found error for all referers from **http://www.example.com** , you can change the **example.com** string to **domain.com** your desired domain to block their referer.