# Block URL to my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to block specific website that refers my site, a paid site that is linking to my site.  I receive many emails requesting cancellation, when in fact, it's not even possible on my site because I don't charge.

.htaccess using

```
deny access members.website.com
```

Comment: Websites don't visit other websites. Do you mean referring?

Comment: You are correct, thanks.

Comment: Here's a non-mod-rewrite solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/27920349/283366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} members\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm already using RewriteEngine, what does the last line mean exactly?  Does it apply to the HTTP_REFERER?

Comment: I'm a tad confused, the 403 Forbidden, how is that tied to the one blocked url only?  It's not, correct?