# How to get traffic from a specific country

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

I have a website hosted by an USA company. 
I set Portugal as destination country of my site in google webmasters 
I am using a social network (like facebook, twitter, etc) to advertise the website only to 2 countries: Brazil and Portugal.

But Google analytics only shows that I get only traffic from USA, Russia and others and NONE from Brazil and Portugal

Can somebody hep me here?

Comment: I am getting traffic from those countries, because people from those countries are registering in my website.

Comment: Many factors affect how users decide to visit a website; This includes: website content, website language, relevance to a users' interests, demographic search-ability, marketing spend & reach.

Comment: But What I founf is that Google analytics does not show any trffic from those countries. I have language set as well, I have var GOOG_FIXURL_LANG  for both countries, hreflang as well for both countries. Articles are wtitten in Portuguese

Comment: How old is the website and do you have a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not getting any hits from your Country, not even yours, then you have to **check that the tracking code is correctly installed**.

The best way to check it is by going to your website through your mobile (without wifi), and check if you see your visit in the real-time reports, if you don't see anything, then there is a problem with the code.

Besides from your tracking code being correctly installed. **You must certainly have spam**. Check your referral reports and look for unusual traffic, like share-buttons, traffic2cash, there are hundreds of spammers.

To keep clean your data you have to create a filter. You can find instruction on how to create this filter here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

Hope it helps,