# using .htaccess to limit access to a directory by a referrer

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to forbid access to a specific directory when a certain referrer tries to access anything in it including images and sub-directories. Is there a way to do this within my "global" .htaccess (in public_html) or would I have to create a directory specific one in that directory (eg public_html/phasers ) ?

Comment: Both ways are possible - you'd want to use a `RewriteCond` to limit the referrer checking only to URLs in that specific directory. To get started, I'd Google `htaccess limit referer`

Comment: Possible duplicate with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666318/how-to-block-spam-referrers-like-darodar-com-from-accessing-website

Comment: That limits access to a whole website, not a specific subdirectory.