# How to exclude sharebutton.to sharebutton.to keywords spam referral

Tags: spam

Any idea how to exclude sharebutton.to sharebutton.to keywords referral?

I tried to exclude it by Admin -> Filters - > New Filter - > Non-standard and putting campaign refferal but it`s still appearing in GA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Block Spam Referrers like darodar.com from Accessing Website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666318/how-to-block-spam-referrers-like-darodar-com-from-accessing-website)

Answer (score 0):

Don't create simple exclude filters, or you will have to create a new one each time a spammer shows up.

Instead, **create an Include filter with your valid hostnames**, this will [block all Google Analytics Spam](https://www.ohow.co/ultimate-guide-to-removing-irrelevant-traffic-in-google-analytics/) of this type, no matter if it shows as a referral, keyword, page, etc.

Here is a related thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362