# The Google Analytics Vote For Trump Analytics Spam

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

We were checking newly implemented Google Analytics for our mobile app and surprisingly there are a lot of visitors from multiple countries but in actuality, we haven't released our app for any store and it's just beta between 5 main users.

After checking Google Analytics report in details we have found that it got spammed by Bot call "Trumps Bot" when something happens on your account you can see following lines in your language section.

```
“Secret.ɢoogle.com You are invited! Enter only with this ticket URL. Copy it. Vote for Trump!”
```

[image]

There are a lot of solution available to avoid this data in your reports using the filter but i was just wondering if there is any concrete solution on permanently remove this data from my reports and also is there anything we can do to avoid such data in future as its seriously affecting business strategy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google analytics spam and is not programing related.  It has been talked to death filter it out and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Due the tecnology used on Google Analytics the only way to eliminate this referal is using a filter, check one common point of all this hits . In this case is a hard one, because all the parameters changes , exept for the language, for a well know reason, to see the spam.
So try to use this one, in my case works 
[image]

**I highly recommend you read the community policy, this can be considered as off-topic question**

Answer (score 0):

Analytics spammers are always trying to find new ways of getting attention, and with this one, this spammer hit it big.

It is not possible to permanently remove it unless you delete the whole property. But you can create and advance segment to get a clean view.

But the most important part is blocking it so it doesn't pollutes your data. For this particular type of spam you should create a **custom exclude language filter** with this expression:

> \s[^s]*\s|.{15,}|.|,

That expression will block any hit that doesn't use a proper language. That combined with a valid hostname filter should prevent most of the current spam and save you a lot of headaches.

If you need help, you can [check this step by step guide for building these filters and creating the advanced segment](https://www.ohow.co/ultimate-guide-to-removing-irrelevant-traffic-in-google-analytics/) to remove it from your historical data.

Here is also a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666318/how-to-block-spam-referrers-like-darodar-com-from-accessing-website/28354319#28354319).

Answer (score 0):

Login in to Your Google Analytics account
Select ADMIN Section
Click on All Filters -- **Add Filters**
Give a filter name such as -- **Include only website traffic**
In Predefined section, select  **Include Only**
for more... [Click Here](http://www.engineerschool.in/blog/tips-and-tricks/secret-google-com-you-are-invited-enter-only-with-this-ticket-url-copy-it-vote-for-trump)